# Correct way of implementing Singular Naming Convention and Data Annotations together in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am using `Entity Framework Core 2.2` and all database table names are singular  so I am `overriding` pluralise naming convention in `OnModelCreating`  method

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            foreach (IMutableEntityType entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                entityType.Relational().TableName = entityType.DisplayName();
            }
        }
```

However in some cases entity names are different to table names for example

```
[Table("AzureSchemaVersionExecutionExtract", Schema = "dbo")]
    public class AzureDataExtract
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public DateTime  DateApplied { get; set; }
    }
```

When i run the project it complains as it cannot find the table `AzureDataExtract` so i added following code in `OnModelCreating` method and it works. I need to know is this the correct way to implement `Data Annotations` and `Singular Naming Convention` together

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            foreach (IMutableEntityType entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
            {
                entityType.Relational().TableName = entityType.DisplayName();
            }
            modelBuilder.Entity<AzureDataExtract>().ToTable("AzureSchemaVersionExecutionExtract","dbo");
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possible, but not with public API. But you already are using methods from `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal` namespace, so that shouldn't be a problem - just check out if something is changed when upgrading to a newer EF Core version and update accordingly.

In EF Core 2.2 the trick is to use the internal `Relational()` method accepting `ConfigurationSource` and pass `ConfigurationSource.Convention`. Data annotations and regular fluent API have higher priority, so this will only override the internal EF Core table name convention which uses the `DbSet` name.

```
foreach (var entityType in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes().Where(t => !t.IsOwned())
{
    entityType.AsEntityType().Builder.Relational(ConfigurationSource.Convention)
        .ToTable(entityType.DisplayName());
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution!